# dashDB service not repsonding?

Tags: memory, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Last night, I was receiving memory issues for some of my queries (inner joins on multiple tables) against my dashDB service on Bluemix.  Today, I cannot even access the dashDB service.

When I access my project instance on Bluemix, using my web browser, and choose my dashDB service, I am presented with a grey page and a white spinning wheel.  I never get past that.

Is there an issue with dashDB in general?  Could it be just my instance of it?  Any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: Can you provide the URL of your dashDB web console? dashDB in Bluemix is hosted by a set of servers and maybe just one of them exposes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to be any general problem as shown at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status

I advice to open a ticket to Bluemix Support.

You can do that using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the
  upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI. After opening the support
  widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of
  assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a
  separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you
  cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget. Go to
  http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I heard that the IBM team had to reboot the service on their end.

Things are working for me - I can now access my dashDB service.

Thanks again for replying.